# Web Part Error: This page has exceeded its data fetch limit for connected Web Parts

Tags: sharepoint

I have a display form with two custom list forms and both are connected to each other and they display the results according to the filter. But when ever I sort on any field, it gives the following error:
Web Part Error:  This page has exceeded its data fetch limit for connected Web Parts. Try disconnecting one or more Web Parts to correct the problem.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks
SP

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today while building an IFilterProvider web part.

For me, the solution was to explicitly fire NoFilter in the PartCommunicationMain method. It seems at least NoFilter, ClearFilter or SetFilter must be fired each time this method is invoked.

```
public override void PartCommunicationMain()
{
    // Ensure that all of the Web Part's controls are created.
    EnsureChildControls();
    TriggerNoFilter(this, null);
}

protected virtual void TriggerNoFilter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (NoFilter != null)
        NoFilter(sender, e);
}
```